# Notifications are being delayed in Android Oreo

Tags: android, notifications

I'm working in a reminder application that has worked well in Marshmallow but I have just bought an Xperia XZ1 compact with Android Oreo and notifications are being delayed or maybe even not shown at all. When the time of the reminder goes off, the phone does nothing, but if I unlock the screen then the notification suddenly appears. According to the logs of the application, my broadcast receiver works and receives the alarm in time and then generates a notification successfully. But the system is delaying to show the notification and I don't know the reason. My application has got all the notification permissions, is configured for being ignored from battery saver and so on. Here is the code for showing the notification. As I said, this code always gets executed in time, but the sound of the notification is delayed a random quantity of minutes, or until I turn the screen on manually.

Is there any way to fix this?

```
private void makeNotification(Long rowId, String title, String body) {
    android.app.NotificationManager mgr = (android.app.NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent;

    long notificationId;
    PendingIntent pi;
    if (rowId == null) {
        notificationId = 0;
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderListActivity.class);
        pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    } else {
        notificationId = rowId;
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderEditActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId);
        long rowIdPrimitive = rowId;
        pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int)rowIdPrimitive, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body));

    Notification note = mBuilder.build();

    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // An issue could occur if user ever enters over 2,147,483,647 tasks. (Max int value).
    // I highly doubt this will ever happen. But is good to note.
    int id = (int)((long)notificationId);
    mgr.notify(id, note);
    NotificationManager.setNotified(context, id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens, but for Oreo, don't you need to provide channel and group

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (LOG_DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, " : version : >=O ");


        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel
                (NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        mChannel.setDescription(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.CYAN);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);


        NotificationChannelGroup mGroup = new NotificationChannelGroup(NOTIFICATION_GROUP_ID, NOTIFICATION_GROUP_NAME);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannelGroup(mGroup);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder
                (context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)

                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notification_subtext))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_pawprint)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDeleteIntent(piDismiss)
                //.setContentIntent(pIpanel)
                .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
                .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());

        notification = builder.build();
    }

    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

This one hits perfectly

Comment: Thanks, I will test that. But I thought that channels weren't so necessary. I have another reminder application of another person (https://github.com/jonasbleyl/recurrence/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bleyl/recurrence/utils/NotificationUtil.java), he doesn't use channels, he makes notifications the same way as me, and its application works and mine doesn't.

Comment: you must if I am not wrong, probably crash in O, run the above code if it helps

Comment: I can't find the method NotificationCompat.Builder(Context, int). I must be missing some support library but I can't find it.

Comment: use appcompat 26.1.0

Comment: This works perfectly for Oreo. If someone needs the application to be compatible with Oreo and with older versions, the only thing to do is to use this code when in Oreo, and if the application is in an older version, it works by using the old constructor of NotificationCompat.Builder, the one that accepted a single parameter, the context.

Comment: yeah, that's the story, happy coding